# Concat all values inside a map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a constant result like this :

```
result: Map<string, string[]>
```

When I do a console.log(result) the output is :

```
Map {
 'toto' => [ 'a-1', 'a-2' ],
 'tata' => [ 'b-1', 'b-2' ],
 'titi' => [ 'c-1', 'c-2' ],
}
```

What I want to have, it's a constant globalResult with all values like this:

```
const globalResult = [ 'a-1', 'a-2','b-1','b-2','c-1','c-2' ]
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can get map [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) into an array and then use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method on it like:

```js
const myMap = new Map().set('toto', ['a-1', 'a-2']).set('tata', ['b-1', 'b-2'])
const arr = [...myMap.values()].flat()

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.from` to covert map values into a flat array

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set('a',11)
map.set('b',22)
map.set('c',33)

const array = Array.from(map.values())
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the values of the properties and flat the arrays.

```js
const 
    object = { toto: ['a-1', 'a-2'], tata: ['b-1', 'b-2'], titi: ['c-1', 'c-2'] },
    array = Object.values(object).flat();

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use forEach function.

```js
  const obj = {
     'toto' : [ 'a-1', 'a-2' ],
     'tata' : [ 'b-1', 'b-2' ],
     'titi' : [ 'c-1', 'c-2' ],
    }

    const arr = [];
    Object.values(obj).forEach(value=>arr.push(...value));
    console.log(arr);
```